# How to read the contents of a json post with asp before processing the request?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, iis

What I want to do is extremely simple in php. I just want to read the contents of the post. It also extremely simple on sailsjs / node ... I just return the result from within the async function.

In c# asp the answer is eluding me. I want the function to read the contents of the post before it attempts to process the post.

Sometimes the following code works. Sometimes the reading of the json from the post happens too slowly and jsonText is read as "" so nothing is processed.

In all of the test runs the json is being sent in the body of the post.

What is the best way to return a httpResponse after making sure the contents of the post is read first?

```
public HttpResponseMessage Post()
    {
        string content;
        try
        {
            string result = String.Empty;
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = null;

            string jsonText = String.Empty;
            var syncTask = new Task<string>( () =>  {
                  return Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            });
            /* I'm expecting that this will finish */ 
            syncTask.RunSynchronously();
            jsonText = syncTask.Result;

            /* before this line of code executes */
            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            if (jsonText == "")
            {
                result = "{\"error\":\"body is empty\"}";
                response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            else
            {
                jObject = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw.Parse(jsonText);

                string ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                jObject["ipAddress"] = ipAddress;

                Models.JsonXML jsonXml = new JsonXML(jObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
                System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                document.LoadXml(jsonXml.xml);
                result = ReferralsManager.ProcessReferral(document);
                if (result == "")
                {
                    result = "{}";
                }

                response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            response.Content = new StringContent(result);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            content = ErrorMessage.ServerException(Converter, ex);
            return Request.ToResponseMessage(content);
        }
        finally
        {
            LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info(InfoMessage.FUNC_ENDS, "Process Referral");
        }
    }
```

The working modified code after the answer from @Mekap is

```
    public class ProcessReferralAddressModel {

        public ProcessReferralAddressModel() { }

        public string address { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }

    }

    public class ProcessReferralModel
    {
        public ProcessReferralModel()
        {

        }
        public string uuid { get; set; }
        public DateTime date { get; set; }
        public ProcessReferralAddressModel from { get; set; }
        public ProcessReferralAddressModel[] to { get; set; }
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public string text { get; set; }
        public string html { get; set; }

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Process a referral.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="userid">The userid.</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public HttpResponseMessage Post([FromBody] ProcessReferralModel processReferralModel)
    {
        string content;
        string jsonText = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(processReferralModel) ;

        try
        {
            string result = String.Empty;
            Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject jObject = null;


            System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();

            if (jsonText == "" || jsonText == null )
            {
                result = "{\"error\":\"body is empty\"}";
                response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
            }
            else
            {
                jObject = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject)Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JRaw.Parse(jsonText);

                string ipAddress = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
                jObject["ipAddress"] = ipAddress;

                Models.JsonXML jsonXml = new JsonXML(jObject.ToString(Newtonsoft.Json.Formatting.None));
                System.Xml.XmlDocument document = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
                document.LoadXml(jsonXml.xml);
                result = ReferralsManager.ProcessReferral(document);
                if (result == "")
                {
                    result = "{}";
                }

                response.StatusCode = System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK;
            }
            response.Content = new StringContent(result);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");

            return response;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            content = ErrorMessage.ServerException(Converter, ex);
            return Request.ToResponseMessage(content);
        }
        finally
        {
            LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger().Info(InfoMessage.FUNC_ENDS, "Process Referral");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are the content you're looking to fetch always in your request's body ? If so Asp.Web APi can do it in your place, making sure that you only get the data you've requested

Comment: try marking your method as `async` and then using `await`

Comment: alternatively, you need to make sure you call all `async` methods with `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` at the end to make sure your code waits for completion

Comment: let me know if any of those work and I'll type up a proper answer ;)

Comment: jsonText = syncTask.GetAwaiter().GetResult(); never returns anything. The function now effectively hangs up the server.

Comment: @Mekap ... that's what I'm looking to do.

Comment: @KeithJohnHutchison OK, i wrote a quick walktrough of how to do that in an answer, fell free to ask any further explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The json you're fetching, for our example will look something like

```
{ "ID" : 3,
 "StringCmd" : "ls -l"
}
```

For starters, we are going to write a small class who's representing our data in your web api

```
public class StringCmdModel
{
    public StringCmdModel()
    {
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string StringCmd { get; set; }
}
```

Now, we just have to write our Entry point in our WebAPI :

```
 [HttpPost]
 public HttpResponseMessage PostFonction([FromBody] StringCmdModel NewEntry)
```

You don't have to check for the existence of the data inside the function. But you should still do proper checks on theirs values, in case you get bad formated json or malicious calls.

But, if you get a call  with json that is not matching the `StringCmdModel` you gave in parameter from the body, this function will not be executed, and the server will throw on its own a 500 error.